# Recreating a mutable map in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a mutable map in Haskell

```
emptyMap = Map.empty
m = Map.insert "file1" "something" emptyMap

addMoreFiles name content m = newMap where
    newMap = Map.insert name content m
```

by passing the key and value and the old map but how can I do this over and over again - use addMoreFiles "key" "value" m and the map that it returns to use it again to add new elements to it? Is it possible and how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, you can use recursion, e.g.

```
addAllFiles [] m = m
addAllFiles ((fN,fC):fs) m =
   addMoreFiles fN fC (addAllFiles fs m)
```

Alternatively you can use `foldr`, `foldl'`, `unfoldr`, `iterate`, etc. which are essentially special recursive forms.

If you work within some monads like `ST s`, `IO`, `State t`, then you also have access to mutable references.

Note that this has nothing to do with maps, specifically. You can "repeatedly add 1 to an integer" using recursion as well.